# Force auto-pst-pdf or pst-pdf to work with xetex

Tags: xetex, color, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

Is it possible to force `auto-pst-pdf` or `pst-pdf` to create PDF images and include them if I’m using `xelatex`?

### Background

I have to typset a Book that needs OpenType fonts so I choose `xelatex`. The autor made her graphics with `pstricks`. Everything works fine and I can compile the file and get the PDF with the graphics all right. **But** the PDF must be converted with Acrobat Pro (color conversion to gray scale—I didn’t choose this workflow …) and I get an error when the PDF contains material creadet by PSTricks. My idea to solve this is to export all `{pspictures}` as a PDF image and include these images back to the main file. Thats exactly what `auto-pst-pdf` does when it is used with `pdflatex` but not together with `xelatex` :-(

I have only a german Acrobat but with this images you maybe see my what I mean:
[image: adobe workflow]

### Example Code

The following code works fine with `xelatex` but I need the graphic to be exported and reimported as PDF image.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
   \psline[linecolor=red](1,1)(5,1)(1,4)(1,1)
   \pscurve[linecolor=green,linewidth=2pt,%
     showpoints=true](5,5)(3,2)(4,4)(2,3)
   \pscircle[linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed](3,2.5){1}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
I asked the question at the german board [typografie.info](http://www.typografie.info/2/showthread.php/25202-Farben-konvertieren-in-mit-XeTeX-PSTricks-erstellter-PDF). Maybe there’s a PDF expert who knows how to fix the PDF …

Comment: You can use `pstricks` with XeLaTeX without packages like `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yea I know, but Acrobat isn’t happy with that ;-)

Comment: @Tobi: Did you try post-processing your PDF with GhostScript (PDF-to-PDF)? This tends to make the files smaller (which is why people to do it), but also fixes a number of complaints in my experience.

Comment: @JosephWright: No I didn’t. I have `gs` installed but can’t use it. Could you please tell me the command for this conversion?

Comment: @Tobi Usually something like `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf` works.

Comment: @JosephWright: I was able to create a new PDF but Acrobat doesn’t like it too :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" ... But the PDF must be converted with Acrobat Pro (color conversion to gray scale—I didn’t choose this workflow …) and I get an error when the PDF contains material created by PSTricks."

The following process using Acrobat Pro 9 (Mac version) converts the pdf file containing the image generated by your minimal code to a pdf file containing a grayscale image.

(1) Open the file with Acrobat Pro.

(2) Select Export > Postcript > Postcript

(3) Select "Settings"

(4) Select "Generic Gray Profile" for Color Profile.

(5) Save the file.

(6) Now open the .ps file (either in Acrobat Distiller or in Preview) and save it as a pdf.

The following is the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked fine :-) Unfortunately a few hours too late for the first bounty, but I started a second one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* the answer to your actual question, but rather an advice about your underlying problem.

1. You may want all figures, including the ones created by `pstrick`, to use `cmyk` color model by specifying `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}`.  This might make Acrobat Pro happy (it might dislike the fact that different parts of PDF use different color models).
2. You may want to create grayscale or monochrome PDF using `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}` or `\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}`.  In this case you might not need Acrobat Pro at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this already and it doesn’t change anything …

Comment: You mean option 1 or option 2?  I have a strong suspicion that if option 1 does not work, Acrobat would not like the files from auto-pst-pdf either, and you are left with option 2...

Comment: I tried only option 1 because option 2 is no option (I can’T influence the work flow for this project). But why does Acrobat have a problem. If I use colors (with `xcolor`) and no PSTricks Acrobat is happy …

Answer (score 3):

it works with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{pstricks}
\fi
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{*-*}(5,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

`lualatex -shell-escape <file>`

By the way: you can convert the file into gray scale also by ghostscript

```
gs -sOutputFile=<grayscale.pdf> -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH <color.pdf>
```

Comment: With `lualatex` I get the desired output with external PDF images but it doesn’t work too. There must be a problem with PSTricks … Can I convert the PDF to grayscale with `gs` and use the Gamma Grey 1.8 profile as Acrobat does?

Comment: There is _no_ problem with PSTricks. It is acrobat! For gs see edit

Comment: In my eyes it’s PSTricks because Acrobat works fine with PDF without PSTricks graphics :-P

Comment: The gray conversion worked but I must check if the colors are matching the other parts, which come from MS Word (not my choice!), of the book …